# Params are ignored in my requests.get() in Python

Tags: python, json, python-requests, get

I am new at programming and I am trying to make a request to an specific id using Python.

I tried this:

```
query={'id': '55311130'}
t = requests.get('https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes', params=query)
json_datas = t.json()
print(json_datas)
```

And this:

```
query={'data':{'memes':[{'id': '55311130'}]}}
t = requests.get('https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes', params=query)
json_datas = t.json()
print(json_datas)
```

But params keeps getting ignored and I get the whole page code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don;t think you can pass nested dictionary in params and 1st case should work

Comment: The api you're trying to use doesn't take any params. What it does is return an array of popular memes, so it doesn't even always return the same elements. Read https://imgflip.com/api for more details.

Comment: Thank you both for the information. I finally was able to get it without using the parameters.